# How to change the color of line and fill for the next object to be drawn in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

When I draw a line, it is always black. After having drawn that line I can easily change all properties.

But if I want to draw 101 pink lines I have to change the color of every line drawn either right after drawing or by selecting them later on. When I select the line tool the fill/contour boxes as well as the corresponding dialogue is greyed out.

I want to set the colors and then go and draw everything in that color until I decide to use a different one. Googling seems fruitless, results only deal with changing colors of existing objects.

So, how can I determine the color of object **before** drawing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Edit > Preferences*, go into *Tools* and select *Pen*, then select "Last used style". Note that "Pen" in the preferences means the "Bézier tool".  Slightly confusing.

[image]

Now when you draw, the tool will remember the last style you chose. The same options are available for various tools, such as the Pencil, Calligraphic tool, the Shape tools, Text tool, etc

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!